# Logic Pro X jumps back when starting recording

Tags: logic-pro

In Logic, the main track view is suddenly jumping back to the beginning of the track (or clip?) when I hit record, even though record begins from later on project. If I enable the Auto-Follow it then jumps back then forward quickly afterwards as per it's functionality.

Is this a bug or a setting somewhere? It's rather annoying as the auto-follow has a habit of turning itself off quick frequently.

Comment: pre-roll ? https://support.apple.com/kb/PH13386?viewlocale=en_US

Comment: Even when off :/

Comment: This happened to me before. I can't remember exactly what I did to solve it, but I think it was an issue with the project so I just transferred all of the project data to a new project and it was fine. There are a lot of weird bugs in logic. Restarting logic usually fixes most of them, but I'm sure that's the first thing you tried.

Answer (score 0):

That could be a bug, yes… Check your software version, and try to update it if possible (if it is the latest update, then it might be an update bug… you're screwed if that's the case, LoL!) :D

Or… You should check where the loop selection is. (The yellow bar in the ruler timeline). Either try turning loop mode off, because generally it records where the selection is placed.

Answer (score 0):

do you have a region selected at the beginning by any chance?
or 
the track is highlighted - hence all the regions are selected?

I've setup my LPX so that whenever I select a region, no matter where the playhead is, jumps and plays from there

Comment: Hmm...maybe it has to do with inadvertently selecting the whole track. I'll have a look next time it happens...